# Не работает SqlDependency в asp.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, sqldependency

Всем привет у меня такой вопрос.  пробую использовать SqlDependency в проекте но оно ни как не работает. Пользовался примерами из интернета но оно ни как не работает.

```
public ChatData()
    {
        //Stop Dependency if they has
        SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
        //Start Dependency
        SqlDependency.Start(connString);

    }
    //Destructor
    ~ChatData()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    }
public List<Chat> getChat()
    {
        string Operator_ID = "1";
        SqlDataReader reader;
        List<Chat> ListChat = new List<Chat>();
        using (SqlConnection sql_connection=new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand("Select ID as Chat_ID, Subject_ID as Subject, User_ID as Phone_Number, Private_Auth, Client_Name, Client_ID,(Select COUNT(*) from MIB_Message_Comment where Status_Read=0 AND Sender_User_ID=User_ID AND Chat_ID=ID)as  Count, Status from MIB_Message_Chat where Online_Consulting=1 And Operator_ID=1", sql_connection);
            sql_command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Operator_Id", Operator_ID));
            sql_command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(sql_command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange_Chat);
            if (sql_connection.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sql_connection.Open();
            }
            reader = sql_command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Chat chat = new Chat();
                    chat.Phone_Number = reader["Phone_Number"].ToString();
                    chat.Num_Chat = reader["Chat_ID"].ToString();
                    chat.Private_Auth = reader["Private_Auth"].ToString();
                    chat.Status = reader["Status"].ToString();
                    chat.Subject = reader["Subject"].ToString();
                    ListChat.Add(chat);
                }
            }
            return ListChat;
        }
    }
    void OnChange_Chat(Object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        index chat = new index();
        chat.UpdateListCHat();
    }
```

А вот обработчик для собитий

```
public void UpdateListCHat()
        {

            var lisChat = chatData.getChat();
            foreach (var item in lisChat)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Num_Chat + " " + item.Phone_Number + " " + item.Subject);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `dependency` - локальная переменная. Возможно, её убирает сборщик мусора.

Comment: проверил не из за этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. проблема в том что для sqldependency нельзя использовать агрегатори типа Count, AVG, SUMM, MAX... Так же вложенние запросы